# Line break not being inserted correctly on an array

Tags: c#

I have text file that is used to store a list of banned domains which is also displayed on a page within a table, however even though a line break is inserted, it is still writing to one row as a single string. If anyone has any ideas as to why it is doing this it would be much appreciated!

```
    private void GetNote()
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(MapPath(FILE_PATH));

    bannedDomains.InnerText = string.Join("\r\n", lines);
    //bannedDomains.InnerText = File.ReadAllText(MapPath(FILE_PATH));
}

private void SaveNote()
{
    File.AppendAllText(MapPath(FILE_PATH), "\r\n" + bannedDomainText.Text);

    //using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(MapPath(FILE_PATH)))
    //{
    //    tw.WriteLine(bannedDomainText.Text);
    //}
}
```

Comment: `bannedDomains.InnerText` is different from `bannedDomainText.Text`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Where is problem with file? If you open it or if you displays it in a web page?
Quoting: `...which is also displayed on a page within a table...` if on web page, you have to use html tag `<br>`

Comment: The problem is with the actual displaying on the page as it doesn't appear to be taking into account the line breaks within the actual file and displaying as one long string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are outputting to HTML, `\r\n` doesn't help -- you must put `<br />` instead.

Comment: I have actually tried that already put it prints out in plain text opposed to html.

Comment: Could this possibly be because the string is being inserted into a table opposed to just a paragraph or something similar?

Comment: BTW, use `InnerHTML` rather than `InnerText`.

Comment: How odd.. I will try inserting the break tag again and I will post my results!

Comment: Success! Thank you very much Roy :) I will accept your answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

try `Environment.NewLine`

```
 Console.WriteLine("NewLine: {0}  first line{0}  second line{0}  third line",
                          Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br />` instead to insert the line break in case of `HTML` and `System.Environment.NewLine` in case of plain text file or simple string.